# how long might the regulatory action against Meta’s GDPR flouting take to play out?

Tags: gdpr

Meta Inc is known to flout subject access request under the GDPR and numerous complaints have been lodged. What is the timeframe for these processes to play out?

[How does Facebook justify non-compliance with GDPR subject access requests?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80794/how-does-facebook-justify-non-compliance-with-gdpr-subject-access-requests)

Comment: I don't know enough to offer an answer, but these from the ICO may be of some use to others: [An organisation normally has to respond to your request within one month](https://ico.org.uk/for-the-public/your-right-to-get-copies-of-your-data/what-to-expect-after-making-a-subject-access-request/#:~:text=An%20organisation%20normally%20has%20to,extra%20two%20months%20to%20respond.) and [What to do if the organisation does not respond](https://ico.org.uk/for-the-public/your-right-to-get-copies-of-your-data/what-to-do-if-the-organisation-does-not-respond-or-you-are-dissatisfied-with-the-outcome/)

Comment: As noted in my comment to the linked question, the Irish DPC tends to be an enforcement bottleneck. The most high-profile enforcement case against Facebook/Meta was Max Schrem's complaint regarding unlawful data transfers, filed the day GDPR came into force in May 2018. The DPC had to be sued to do its job, with appeals up to the CJEU. This took over two years. Once the CJEU had found that the data transfers had been illegal, the EDPB had to overrule the DPC to actually draw consequences, like imposing fines. All of this took around five years, and the matter still isn't completely settled.

Comment: @amon do you know where one can read about the progress of these matters?